# How to return a status code from a IHttpControllerSelector?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944864(v%3Dvs.118)

I'm currently implementing API versioning. When an invalid version is supplied I would like to respond with status code 406. How would I do this from `IHttpControllerSelector`'s SelectController method?

Currently thinking about creating some sort of ErrorController and routing to that, but not sure if there are any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new controller that returns the Http 406. 
Create a HttpControlDescriptor  and override CreateController to create the new controller.
The IHttpControllerSelector implementation then returns the control descriptor that then constructs the controller that returns the version is invalid.

Comment: How would this new controller return the Http 406? Currently it has 1 method (`public HttpResponseMessage Handle()`) that returns the response, however it is never being called. Does the overriden CreateController method need to do something else besides creating the Controller (e.g. link to the Handle method somehow?)

Answer (score 0):

Currently created an error controller that handles the exception, routing to it with:

```
var routeData = request.GetRouteData().Values;

routeData.Clear();
routeData["controller"] = "Error";
routeData["problemDetails"] = problemDetails;

return base.SelectController(request);
```

It works but I'm not a big fan, leaving this question open for a while incase there are any bettter alternatives.